# Meteor #each and session data

Tags: javascript, meteor

I have a template that is based on a async information, so I use the `Session` data in order to reactively render the view when the data arrive. Something like:

item.html:

```
<template name="item">
    {{#with item}}
        {{itemInformation.name}}
    {{/with}}
</template>
```

item.js

```
Template.item.created = function () {
    getItemData(this.data.item.id, function(data) {
        Session.set("itemInformation", data);
    });
}

Template.item.helpers({
    itemInformation: function() {
        return Session.get("itemInformation");
    }
});
```

This approach seems to work fine if I have one item template active. But if I use this approach in a `#each` loop I'm getting to collisions on the session data.

1. Is there a "local" `Session` data I can use?
2. What is the right approach to re-render view when based on a async data in `#each` loop?

Comment: See [this post](http://dweldon.silvrback.com/scoped-reactivity) for a complete discussion of this exact issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can create a ReactiveDict (https://atmospherejs.com/meteor/reactive-dict  - Session actually uses it in its implementation) in the onCreated template callback (`self.localSession  = new ReactiveDict ()`), and use it instead of Session (`self.localSession.set('itemInformation', data)`).
   You can access it in the template helper this way: `Template.instance().localSession.get('itemInformation')`.

If it is just one item you want to store in the dictionary, you can also just use single ReactiveVar (https://atmospherejs.com/meteor/reactive-var) in the same manner.

2. Just like you noticed, you need to set the async content in some reactive source, you can use the constructs I described above.

Your code:

```
Template.item.created = function () {
     var self = this;
     self.localSession  = new ReactiveDict ();
     getItemData(self.data.item.id}, function(data) {
         self.localSession.set("itemInformation", data);
    });
}

Template.item.helpers({
    itemInformation: function() {
        return Template.instance().localSession.get("itemInformation");
    }
});
```

Comment: That works great and it's much better approach than that I tried which abuse the SessionData.

Answer (score 1):

[`Session`](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/session) is a [global named `ReactiveDict`](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/devel/packages/session/session.js#L1) used when you want to share data between various parts of your application. Since it's a global you probably don't want to clutter it too much.

Why even use a `ReactiveDict`? If you're going to store only one item per template then a [`ReactiveVar`](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/reactivevar) is the obvious way to go! Plus, `ReactiveVar` can contain *anything*, while [`ReactiveDict` instances may only contain EJSON-able values](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/devel/packages/reactive-dict/reactive-dict.js#L61).

Thus,

```
Template.item.created = function () {
    getItemData(this.data.item.id, data => {
        this.item = new ReactiveVar(data);
    });
}

Template.item.helpers({
    itemInformation: () => Template.instance().item
});
```

Note that each template will update according to subsequent `set` of their own `ReactiveVar` instance. If you wish to regularly update them with `getItemData` you don't have many options.
Since it's an async method you're out of luck. Your best bet is to regularly poll for data with [`Meteor.setInterval`](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/meteor_setinterval) and `item.set()` the resulting data in your callback. I have done something similar [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31972889/4174897) for a synchronous getter, you'd have to tweak the implementation.

Don't forget to [`Meteor.clearInterval`](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/meteor_clearinterval) in the `onDestroyed` callback of your template if you use the polling strategy described above.